# How to select different subscriptions from azure using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I am automating the creation of resources in azure but for that I need to to extract the subscriptions one by one and create the resources.

For eg:Suppose I have these 3 subscriptions on my azure account

```
A-prod, B-prod, C-prod
```

Now first I am listing these subscriptions through the command :

```
$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
```

It would give me the name of all the 3 subscriptions.

Now I want to select the subscriptions one by one .
I want to choose **A-prod** and add resources to that subscription through the script and after it is completed I want to move to the next subscription i.e. **B-prod** ,adding subscription to B-prod and moving onto the next subscription,  this process will go on till the last subscription.
We can use for loop here but I am not able to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

when you change the subscription id, you could do it

```
$ApplicationId = "0000-0000-0000-0000"
$Password = "000000000000000"
$TenantId = "0000-0000-000-000"
$subscriptionId = "0000-0000-0000-0000"
$SecuredPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ApplicationId, $SecuredPassword
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential
$sub = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
Set-AzContext -Subscription $sub
```